# Difference between AppiumDriver<MobileElement> and AndroidDriver

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium

I am automating android app using Appium (java).
I searched at many places but couldn't find out exact differences between the two drivers mentioned below.

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver
AndroidDriver driver
```

What is difference between them and which one to use when and why?
Any explaination / link / example would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition from `io.appium.java_client.android`

```
public class AndroidDriver<RequiredElementType extends WebElement> 
    extends AppiumDriver<RequiredElementType> implements AndroidDeviceActionShortcuts,
    HasNetworkConnection,PushesFiles, StartsActivity, FindsByAndroidUIAutomator<RequiredElementType> {
```

AppiumDriver is the super driver for Android driver. So now you shall know, if you are using super driver what all do you have and if you are using the derived driver what all would  be getting to use.

Note : `AndroidDriver` and `IOSDriver` are derived for different platforms to implement their specific capabilities abstracting one's from the other's.

Though this should not be generalised in anyway, personally I would suggest using AppiumDriver in case of doubts over which to use and how to access elements on the apps.

Answer (score 4):

The main differences between Appium and AndroidDriver/iPhoneDriver are architectural.

The AndroidDriver/iPhoneDriver work the same basic way - they are applications you launch on the phone that create a webview that you can remote control with selenium. The limitations to this approach are:

Appium works by wrapping the first-party automation frameworks (UIAutomator for iPhone and UI Automation/Instrumentation for Android).

- You can drive an actual browser, with all the browser's functionality.
- Operating system control - you can change the OS settings, clear data, and     sleep apps, in addition to any hooks exposed by the OS for testing
- You can automate native code in addition to web testing.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer.Just one more thing - I am automating native app with some hybrid features.So which one to prefer? Its misbehaving for hybrid components.Also, UI Automator also doesnt provide much for webview subcomponents

Comment: I prefer to go with Androiddriver